# Reverse the contents of each line in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was hoping someone could help me, I need to reverse the contents of each line in a file.  So basically this:
101.228.168.192
to
192.168.228.101
Is there a command I could use in a bash script, or even just the logic needed to get the job done.  Thanks

Comment: are all the lines guaranteed to be in a x.x.x.x format?

Comment: yes, we could - but it would be better if you posted what you have tried and then asked for critiques - just sayin'

Answer (score 6):

You could use awk:

```
awk -F'.' '{print $4"."$3"."$2"."$1}' file.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -nl -e 'print join(".", reverse( split /\./ ))' filename.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your method, and it does what I needed as well

Answer (score 3):

```
 sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\4.\3.\2.\1/g' filename.txt
```

thanks for the comment Sean

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution

```
while IFS="." read -r A B C D; do
  echo "$D.$C.$B.$A"
done < file
```